# Exception for a certain controller in Yii

Tags: php, yii

i have a lot of controller in my yii-application. all of them are only accessable if you are logged in, otherwise you will be redirect to the login-page. 
But i have one controller with some actions who should be accesable for everybody. How can i configure Yii to make that happens?

I have tried a lot in the accessRules() function of the controller, but nothing works.

```
  public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('allow', 'users' => array('*'))
    );
  }
```

i am expecting not to get redirected to the login page.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with that code. If you intend to allow *all* actions to be accessible by everyone, remove the `accessControl` filter and the `accessRules()` implementation entirely.

**Update:**

Well, if your base `Controller` attaches access control rules to all application controllers you simply need to override the appropriate methods in order to restore [default](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/CController.php#154) [behavior](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/CController.php#239):

```
public function filters()
{
    return array();
}

public function accessRules()
{
    return array();
}
```

However, if `Controller` attaches more filters than just `accessControl` you will have to somehow find which one is the `accessControl` line and remove only that. Which is not trivial, because there's quite a bit of syntax that can go in there.

In the end, `Controller` should not be doing that. If you wanted to share behavior between many, but not all, front-line controllers then you should have created another class e.g. `ControllerWithAccessControl` and derive from it *selectively*.

Comment: i have tried that before. I still get redirected to the login-page. maybe i have to change something in the main.php, but i don't know what.

Comment: @ESCOBAR: Perhaps a base controller class provides default values? We 're really into debugging territory here.

Comment: the base controller ist the Yii-Controller named "Controller". Here we have the function filters() and accesRules(). But i have to overwrite these functions in my controller to avoid the default behavior. My Question is: How should the overwritten functions look like?

Comment: your code-sample was the first thing i have tried. it should work, but....
now i will try the other way with the new Controller. THX

Comment: i have found the problem....in one action of my controller i have tried to create a object of a wrong model... -.- anyhow, thank you for your help!